# if was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am facing a compilation issue for `IF` condition, while some other script at the same location uses the same condition works fine. Another script also checks whether Release folder is present in the code or not, it is not it will do some operation. Any idea why the same `IF` is failing as I am calling from the same location?

```
@echo OFF

cd ..
cd debug/bin/8209

if not exist Release (
set val2 ""
echo %val2%
echo start the script 

readelf qcdsp28909.mbn -l | awk '{if (match($6,/0x/)){if ($1 == "LOAD" ) print strtonum($6)}}'|  awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024/1024}' > value.txt 2>&1

set /p size=<value.txt

echo %size%

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a  in ("%size%") do (
  set first_part=%%a
  set second_part=%%b
)

set second_part=%second_part:~0,1%
echo %second_part%
if defined second_part if %second_part% GEQ 5 ( 

    set /a rounded=%first_part%+1
) else ( 
    set /a rounded=%first_part%
)

echo %rounded%

set /a rounded= "%rounded% * 1024 * 1024"

echo %rounded%

call cmd /c exit /b %rounded%
set hex=%=exitcode%


set val2=%hex%
setx val2 %hex% /m
echo %val2%
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `awk` statements and use double quotes instead of single, then use single within.

```
readelf qcdsp28909.mbn -l | awk "{if (match($6,/0x/)){if ($1 == 'LOAD' ) print strtonum($6)}}" | awk "{ sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024/1024}" > value.txt 2>&1
```

That way the parentheses within your `awk` statements won't be evaluated as part of the batch parenthetical code block (the `if not exist Release (...)` block) it lives in.

Comment: I already tried that change, but putting " " is not giving me desired output. It is returning value 0 as output.

Comment: Sorry, I know very little of `awk` syntax.  Maybe is your `sum` variable cast as a string or an integer when it should be a float?  You might have better luck asking tagging a new question as `awk`.  You might also try putting your awk arguments into a `.awk` file and trying `awk -f "scriptfile.awk"`, just to rule out the possibility of a problem specific to the command line.  By the way, what is `strtonum` doing?  Your second awk statement has no way to know that the output of the first `awk` went through `strtonum`.